# How can I choose one elements inside of v-loop? (vue.js)

Tags: vue.js

I want to make a function which when user click then it doesn't show anymore. but that box is inside of for loop so I don't know how to access only one element from inside of loop.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="box" @click="click(i)" v-for="(d,i) in data" :key="i">
      {{d}}
      <div v-if="select" class="el">here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  name: "Test",
  data() {
    return {
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
      select: true
    };
  },
  methods: {
    click(i) {
      this.select === false;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: you could make a method that takes the index and removes it form the array with that; the best approach would be to remove it by some unique identifier actually _on_ the array item (like an ID or the like)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to go about it.

One way to go about it is transforming that array of numbers, in an array of objects.

This is a snippet of a working example.

https://playcode.io/608867/